# How do I generate SSHFP records?

Tags: ssh, dns, openssl

I need to setup SSHFP records in the DNS for my host. I have done some searching but I haven't found any good example.

- What are SSHFP records?
- What does SSHFP records look like?
- How do I create SSHFP records?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

### What are SSHFP records?

SSHFP records are DNS records that contain fingerprints for public keys used for SSH. They're mostly used with DNSSEC enabled domains. When an SSH client connects to a server it checks the corresponding SSHFP record. If the records fingerprint matches the servers, the server is legit and it's safe to connect.

### What does SSHFP records look like?

SSHFP records consist of three things:

1. Public key algorithm
2. Fingerprint type
3. Fingerprint (in hex)

#### Public key algorithm

There are five different algorithms defined in SSHFP *as of 2021*. Each algorithm is represented by an integer. [The algorithms are](https://www.iana.org/assignments/dns-sshfp-rr-parameters/dns-sshfp-rr-parameters.xhtml#dns-sshfp-rr-parameters-1):

- 1 - RSA
- 2 - DSA
- 3 - ECDSA
- 4 - Ed25519
- 6 - Ed448

#### Fingerprint type

Two fingerprint types are defined in SSHFP *as of 2012*. Each fingerprint type is represented by an integer. [These are](https://www.iana.org/assignments/dns-sshfp-rr-parameters/dns-sshfp-rr-parameters.xhtml#dns-sshfp-rr-parameters-2):

- 1 - SHA-1
- 2 - SHA-256

### How do I generate SSHFP records?

You can use [ssh-keygen](http://man.he.net/?topic=ssh-keygen&section=all) locally to generate the records using the `-r` parameter, followed by the hostname (which does not affect the fingerprints so you can specify whatever you like instead).

You can use ssh-keyscan to generate records for a remote server using the `-D` parameter, followed by the hostname.

### Example

Using `ssh-keygen` and CentOS:

```
[root@localhost ~]# ssh-keygen -r my.domain.com
my.domain.com IN SSHFP 1 1 450c7d19d5da9a3a5b7c19992d1fbde15d8dad34
my.domain.com IN SSHFP 2 1 72d30d211ce8c464de2811e534de23b9be9b4dc4
```

#### Note

Sometimes `ssh-keygen` will ask for the location of the public certificate. If it asks, you will have to run `ssh-keygen` multiple times and every time specify a different certificate to make sure that you generate all necessary SSHFP records. Your public keys are usually located in `/etc/ssh`.

Comment: `ssh-keygen -r` also handles ed25519 type records (using the experimental number 4 from iana http://www.iana.org/assignments/dns-sshfp-rr-parameters/dns-sshfp-rr-parameters.xhtml )

Comment: The server is legit, *or* the DNS server is compromised.

Answer (score 11):

I'm not sure if `ssh-keygen` works with existing keys. If not you still can easily assemble them in your shell (which I prefer), and without fancy software or remote interfaces.

A records such as mentioned...

```
my.domain.com IN SSHFP 2 1 72d30d211ce8c464de2811e534de23b9be9b4dc4
```

...exist of 6 parts:

```
part 1: hostname
part 2: Usually "IN" for internet
part 3: "SSHFP", the RR name for type 44
part 4: RSA keys     = "1"
        DSA keys     = "2"
        ECDSA keys   = "3"
        Ed25519 keys = "4"
        Ed448 keys   = "6"
part 5: The algorithm type:
        SHA-1        = "1"
        SHA-256      = "2"
part 6: You can generate, for example:

        $ awk '{print $2}' /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key.pub | \
            openssl base64 -d -A | openssl sha1
```

To make use of it, put `VerifyHostKeyDNS ask` in your SSH client's config, usually `~/.ssh/config`.

Comment: For the record, `ssh-keygen -r` *does* generate SSHFP records for existing keys despite the fact that the name of the command suggests it's only for GENerating.

Answer (score 6):

Older versions of ssh-keygen don't generate all the available keys (eg. no support for ecdsa and sha256). This script does creates all the records for all available keys in `/etc/ssh/`:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
#
# Creates SSHFP Records for all available keys
#

HOST="${1-$(hostname -f)}"

if [[ "$1" == "-h" || "$1" == "--help" ]]
then
  echo "Usage: sshfpgen <hostname>"
fi

if which openssl >/dev/null 2>&1
then
  if ! which sha1sum >/dev/null 2>&1
  then
    sha1sum() {
      openssl dgst -sha1 | grep -E -o "[0-9a-f]{40}"
    }
  fi
  if ! which sha256sum >/dev/null 2>&1
  then
    sha256sum() {
      openssl dgst -sha256 | grep -E -o "[0-9a-f]{64}"
    }
  fi
fi

for pubkey in /etc/ssh/ssh_host_*_key.pub /etc/ssh_host_*_key.pub
do
  case "$(cut -d _ -f3 <<< "$pubkey")"
  in
    rsa)
      echo "$HOST IN SSHFP 1 1 $(cut -f2 -d ' ' "$pubkey" | base64 --decode | sha1sum  | cut -f 1 -d ' ')"
      echo "$HOST IN SSHFP 1 2 $(cut -f2 -d ' ' "$pubkey" | base64 --decode | sha256sum  | cut -f 1 -d ' ')"
    ;;
    dsa)
      echo "$HOST IN SSHFP 2 1 $(cut -f2 -d ' ' "$pubkey" | base64 --decode | sha1sum  | cut -f 1 -d ' ')"
      echo "$HOST IN SSHFP 2 2 $(cut -f2 -d ' ' "$pubkey" | base64 --decode | sha256sum  | cut -f 1 -d ' ')"
    ;;
    ecdsa)
      echo "$HOST IN SSHFP 3 1 $(cut -f2 -d ' ' "$pubkey" | base64 --decode | sha1sum  | cut -f 1 -d ' ')"
      echo "$HOST IN SSHFP 3 2 $(cut -f2 -d ' ' "$pubkey" | base64 --decode | sha256sum  | cut -f 1 -d ' ')"
    ;;
    ed25519)
      echo "$HOST IN SSHFP 4 1 $(cut -f2 -d ' ' "$pubkey" | base64 --decode | sha1sum  | cut -f 1 -d ' ')"
      echo "$HOST IN SSHFP 4 2 $(cut -f2 -d ' ' "$pubkey" | base64 --decode | sha256sum  | cut -f 1 -d ' ')"
    ;;
    ed448)
      echo "$HOST IN SSHFP 6 1 $(cut -f2 -d ' ' "$pubkey" | base64 --decode | sha1sum  | cut -f 1 -d ' ')"
      echo "$HOST IN SSHFP 6 2 $(cut -f2 -d ' ' "$pubkey" | base64 --decode | sha256sum  | cut -f 1 -d ' ')"
    ;;
  esac
done
```

Edit: New Version with PR from alex-dupuy with *BSD support.

https://github.com/mindfuckup/Scripts/blob/master/sshfpgen

Answer (score 3):

If you use Puppet, `facter` has built in support for [`sshfp`](https://github.com/puppetlabs/facter/blob/8be4d00b8d4457062ac36dbbf44073b10c060490/lib/facter/ssh.rb#L45). Plus if you are using PuppetDB you can easily extract this info for all your hosts.

```
facter | grep -i sshfp
  sshfp_dsa => SSHFP 2 1 e1a3e639d6dbd48d3964ebfb772d2d11f1065682
  SSHFP 2 2 4f620ce2bc97d91ae5eff42fba621d65b677ab725f275f56b2abd1303c142b73
  sshfp_rsa => SSHFP 1 1 a78351af371faf3f19533c3a4a9e967543d7d2f5
  SSHFP 1 2 795943a6ee8b53c818cfef5781209e25a6eb4bc386813db60d3ff2c1569692fc
```

Answer (score 3):

This is how I'm getting my SSHFP records through [Ansible](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ansible):

```
- name: Capture the SSHFP entries
  shell: "ssh-keygen -r {{ ansible_nodename }}|awk '{print $4, $5, $6}'"
  register: sshfp_entries
```

Answer (score 1):

This one works even better:

Source: https://weberblog.net/generating-sshfp-records-remotely/

```bash
# Source: https://gist.github.com/webernetz/2ca7325555ce7f28f26daf5728386d82
wget https://gist.githubusercontent.com/webernetz/2ca7325555ce7f28f26daf5728386d82/raw/1c18dc43a05478771ac4693401a3c78205a4e710/grabsshfp.sh
chmod u+x grabsshfp.sh

# Run it (will check: rsa dsa ecdsa ed25519)

weberjoh@nb15-lx:~$ ./grabsshfp.sh pa-mgmt
pa-mgmt IN SSHFP 1 1 4addde64e14a19e6a2286ca422ca0b9bd322c31d
pa-mgmt IN SSHFP 1 2 ca0acaa29d0cb233b2a715be3217a91002efe87d7e28bd51314b1feef203c5a7
```