# What's the simplest way to convert between SSHFP hex and ssh-keygen SHA256 Base64?

Tags: ssh

I am trying to verify the SSH fingerprint of a GitLab server. Its [published fingerprints](https://gitlab.gnome.org/help/instance_configuration) are wrong, possibly from load balancing. [`VerifyHostKeyDNS=yes`](https://wiki.gnome.org/GitLab) doesn't error but I don't trust not seeing fingerprints and would like to do so without connecting.

[SSHFP](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/121881/524752) SHA1 and SHA256 are in hex. I would also prefer the numeric IDs like "4 2" to be converted to English names like "SHA256 (ED25519)".

```
$ resolvectl query -t sshfp ssh.gitlab.gnome.org
ssh.gitlab.gnome.org IN SSHFP 1 1 9d319c15965b939bc2086cbebca96d8bbb89e9a3 -- link: enp39s0
ssh.gitlab.gnome.org IN SSHFP 1 2 591469a16a3bb33333c2591815e2e88f4508b665477c023eafe845833c060118 -- link: enp39s0
ssh.gitlab.gnome.org IN SSHFP 3 1 17b29179778339d7c91cb2c281b7afa2798c61d5 -- link: enp39s0
ssh.gitlab.gnome.org IN SSHFP 3 2 4e203da68ea73ba8c5b28ef040dcb8c4b96d875d2521f8efd5dc6e0da6d522ac -- link: enp39s0
ssh.gitlab.gnome.org IN SSHFP 4 1 457e9cb0d575697e27fe8b2185580df5d45ce46b -- link: enp39s0
ssh.gitlab.gnome.org IN SSHFP 4 2 63d1b87568887e2e772d1dc89c95ac21bbf895e9141e89eafc7aea4d39bfadcc -- link: enp39s0

-- Information acquired via protocol DNS in 1.1133s.
-- Data is authenticated: yes; Data was acquired via local or encrypted transport: yes
-- Data from: network
```

However, [`ssh-keyscan`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/268692/524752) gives me Base64 for SHA1 and SHA256. Only the MD5 absent from SSHFP would be in hex. SHA256 Base64 is also the format that `git` prompts me with when connecting. My use case is to manually inspect the fingerprint, then somehow trust it into `~/.ssh/known_hosts`. For simplicity, I only care about ED25519.

```
$ ssh-keyscan ssh.gitlab.gnome.org | tee gnome.pub
# ssh.gitlab.gnome.org:22 SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.0
ssh.gitlab.gnome.org ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5AAAAIHG6b3deoYMPwKEu9Sj+y6MBHYYUKQiAnta/go3aNv7R
# ssh.gitlab.gnome.org:22 SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.0
ssh.gitlab.gnome.org ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABgQCmUnZ33O26kvhcmc6k1T8xlL3yJjeNt3gphvW9/5u/CO0z5G8PGr2km4jUhStuPJR9m77LrdCF5Ywm26hsBnoxK+1zMs7YTjriiGt4r0Q5btQS5J5zFAV6aYJEmCbQz/23n8+w9Jx3hPVS8A3VE9Vd52S+5DMeIQY8QR3LPpROyCIpkR425sN0D0VjRUAH0hn61zS8N1+Pw5te2ULbBriBB9cub2n1GBCsZ2ErX1ernwKffOz/fbi5mpGbGLlJabLBm81/AiNk6NLZWTAZiNZjztxRySZFSpSzGF54kttIePxNC1x9AtW4KMaIzjVK2DIrFONyZYiEX47ox5TXlc7VQaBICUoTrR91wpb5xl2HPKP4MvFqUAzubU2V8r91ISXrnJyfwDrSB7L9Jwg6B6pN+acIttC4gOFGTJg9qanmLxtonSpwv/NaLehI1+D4LR9Or+e8jjtKSc6vu8+ghqAni3XHoT9uSmt1UPd89dOhqbpk8Hc3KTubUC3WIjGnotE=
# ssh.gitlab.gnome.org:22 SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.0
ssh.gitlab.gnome.org ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 AAAAE2VjZHNhLXNoYTItbmlzdHAyNTYAAAAIbmlzdHAyNTYAAABBBH8NuGQ3ArFGochlv6TKXhMhsgIwG743e93pLkAQTzfgds0g0k6QBimb40zavVjITjytiSaQsf+KncJgUjYd98o=
# ssh.gitlab.gnome.org:22 SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.0
# ssh.gitlab.gnome.org:22 SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.0
$ <gnome.pub ssh-keygen -lf -
3072 SHA256:WRRpoWo7szMzwlkYFeLoj0UItmVHfAI+r+hFgzwGARg ssh.gitlab.gnome.org (RSA)
256 SHA256:TiA9po6nO6jFso7wQNy4xLlth10lIfjv1dxuDabVIqw ssh.gitlab.gnome.org (ECDSA)
256 SHA256:Y9G4dWiIfi53LR3InJWsIbv4lekUHonq/HrqTTm/rcw ssh.gitlab.gnome.org (ED25519)
```

How can I reconcile the two formats? Ideally I would like a few flags to pass `ssh-*` or other commands.

The following commands might give the correct answers but are unacceptable because they are too long to remember/type and are formatted badly. My use case would be to run these once when setting up a new computer, so `.bashrc` aliases won't be present.

```bash
(x="$(<gnome.pub)"; for y in sha1 sha256; do echo "$x" | ssh-keygen -lf - -E "$y"; done) | xargs -d\\n -n1 bash -c "echo \"\$0\"; echo \"\$0\" | sed 's/[^:]\+:\([^ ]\+\).*/\1=/' | base64 -d | xxd -p -c 32"
resolvectl query -t sshfp ssh.gitlab.gnome.org | grep ' IN SSHFP ' | xargs -n1 -d\\n bash -c 'echo "$0"; echo "$0" | cut -d\  -f 6 | xxd -p -r | base64'
grep -v \# gnome.pub | cut -d\  -f2- | xargs -n1 -d\\n bash -c 'ssh-keygen -r ssh.gitlab.gnome.org -f <(echo "$0")'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert from base64 to hex, you can use `perl` for instance:

```
$ ssh-keygen -lf gnome.pub | perl -MMIME::Base64 -lpe 's{SHA256:\K\S+}{unpack("H*", decode_base64($&))}e'
256 SHA256:63d1b87568887e2e772d1dc89c95ac21bbf895e9141e89eafc7aea4d39bfadcc ssh.gitlab.gnome.org (ED25519)
3072 SHA256:591469a16a3bb33333c2591815e2e88f4508b665477c023eafe845833c060118 ssh.gitlab.gnome.org (RSA)
256 SHA256:4e203da68ea73ba8c5b28ef040dcb8c4b96d875d2521f8efd5dc6e0da6d522ac ssh.gitlab.gnome.org (ECDSA)
```

`ssh-keyscan` also has a `-D` option to print the output as SSHFP records:

```
$ ssh-keyscan -D ssh.gitlab.gnome.org
; ssh.gitlab.gnome.org:22 SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.0
ssh.gitlab.gnome.org IN SSHFP 1 1 9d319c15965b939bc2086cbebca96d8bbb89e9a3
ssh.gitlab.gnome.org IN SSHFP 1 2 591469a16a3bb33333c2591815e2e88f4508b665477c023eafe845833c060118
; ssh.gitlab.gnome.org:22 SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.0
ssh.gitlab.gnome.org IN SSHFP 3 1 17b29179778339d7c91cb2c281b7afa2798c61d5
ssh.gitlab.gnome.org IN SSHFP 3 2 4e203da68ea73ba8c5b28ef040dcb8c4b96d875d2521f8efd5dc6e0da6d522ac
; ssh.gitlab.gnome.org:22 SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.0
ssh.gitlab.gnome.org IN SSHFP 4 1 457e9cb0d575697e27fe8b2185580df5d45ce46b
ssh.gitlab.gnome.org IN SSHFP 4 2 63d1b87568887e2e772d1dc89c95ac21bbf895e9141e89eafc7aea4d39bfadcc
; ssh.gitlab.gnome.org:22 SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.0
; ssh.gitlab.gnome.org:22 SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.0
```

And `ssh-keygen -r` can give you the SSHFP records for a given public key, so you can also do:

```
$ perl -ne '
  if (/^\s*+([^#]\S*)\s+(.*)/) {
    open K, "|-", qw(ssh-keygen -f /dev/stdin -r), $1;
    print K $2;
    close K;
  }' gnome.pub
ssh.gitlab.gnome.org IN SSHFP 4 1 457e9cb0d575697e27fe8b2185580df5d45ce46b
ssh.gitlab.gnome.org IN SSHFP 4 2 63d1b87568887e2e772d1dc89c95ac21bbf895e9141e89eafc7aea4d39bfadcc
ssh.gitlab.gnome.org IN SSHFP 1 1 9d319c15965b939bc2086cbebca96d8bbb89e9a3
ssh.gitlab.gnome.org IN SSHFP 1 2 591469a16a3bb33333c2591815e2e88f4508b665477c023eafe845833c060118
ssh.gitlab.gnome.org IN SSHFP 3 1 17b29179778339d7c91cb2c281b7afa2798c61d5
ssh.gitlab.gnome.org IN SSHFP 3 2 4e203da68ea73ba8c5b28ef040dcb8c4b96d875d2521f8efd5dc6e0da6d522ac
```

Comment: Thanks for the `ssh-keyscan -D` and the other compact commands! I completely overlooked the `-D` flag. One small thing, is there a way to make `ssh-keyscan` print both the SSHFP and something else like the key or another fingerprint to avoid a TOCTOU between verifying and trusting? If not, I could always recover some confidence by interleaving `ssh`/`git` and `ssh-keyscan` a few times, which is better than nothing when my commands were too long.

Comment: You can always use ssh-keyscan without -D to same in your `gnome.pub`, compare to sshfp queries (making sure the result is signed and validated), and then use `ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=gnome.pub` (or add those to your `~/.ssh/known_hosts`). Or just use `ssh -o VerifyHostKeyDNS` once and let ssh add the keys by itself to do all that process automatically in a safer way.